# MATLAB : Does the command "contour" give the streamlines in a flow simulation?

Tags: matlab, streamline

I'm not sure what command to use on matlab to plot the streamlines in a flow simulation. I used the command "contour" but it seems that it is not the right one.

I tried to use the commands "streamline" and "stream2d" but the starting points are really difficult to choose.

Comment: When I did simulations, I used the command `streamslice` to display the streamlines.

Comment: streamslice is used for 3D cases i think? How did you use it exactly can you give me the instruction ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution it is "quiver" command  (if case anyone needs this)

Answer (score 0):

quiver command is used to generate vector field which predict the direction of velocity components while streamline command is used to generate streamlines. contour plot is basically a surface plot which can be used to plot stream function.